# Anonymous by-name function - execution

Tags: scala

Suppose I have such method definition:

```
def strangeMethod[A](value: => A): A = value;
```

I use it e.g. like that:

```
strangeMethod(() => "foo");
```

For me, expected behavior is returning a String object. Instead it returns:

```
() => String = <function0>
```

Why?

If I try something like this:

```
def strangeMethod[A](value: => A): A = value();
```

I get, of course, compile time error.

I am confused...

PS
I know that i can define it like that:

```
def strangeMethod[A](value: () => A): A = value();
```

And the behavior will be as expected, but why the first example is not working as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `def strangeMethod[A](value: => A): A = value` the `value: => A` is a block that evaluates to `A`, *passed-by-name* - every time you retrieve its value, it will be evaluated again. For example:

```
def strangeMethod2[A](block: => A): A = {block; block}

strangeMethod2({
  val hi = "hi "
  println("middle")
  val dad = "dad"
  hi ++ dad
})
```

gives in console:

```
middle
middle
res0: String = hi dad
```

However `() => "foo"` is a function from `Unit` to a `String` (a function with 0 arguments, [function0](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.Function0)), so when you pass it to `strangeMethod` it will return the very same function - which you can call:

```
scala> strangeMethod(() => "foo")()
res1: String = foo
```

Comment: So it is only specific case when it is without parameters. Means block code to execute. With arguments, so method defined like that: 
    `def strangeMethod[A](value: Int => A): A = value(5);` or that:
    `def strangeMethod[A](value: (Int) => A): A = value(5);`
means always a function to call, and no other differences?